# Should I use an Enum class or a Lookup in c#

Tags: c#, enums

Here is my ultimate goal: I want to have a way of outputting tool names based on whatever integer is registered in the program. For instance, if integers, 1001, 1002, and 1003, where found by the program, then the program would tell the user that Tool 1, Tool 2, and Tool 3 were found.

I have gotten this to work using a simple enum class where all of the "tools" are numbered and correspond to the correct integer. I can even output the enum as a name, although I would like to output a string, preferably one that can be edited easily without having to change the entire program too much. Like it would be great if I could program it all as Tool 1, Tool 3, and Tool 7 now, and then go back and just change the strings when I actually know the tools that I am using.

I have also already tried to use the DescriptionAttribute with this enum, but even with the help of a few questions already, I was not able to figure out how to look up the enum by the integer and then output the Description of that Enum. I could do either or, but not both, simply.

So that led me to wonder if there was a better way that I could handle all of this besides using the Enum class, which I have heard is not as useful in c#. I just want to know any suggestions on how I can do this with an enum class, or other methods within c# that I can use to achieve this.

Just let me know if I need to share my working code that I already have. Thanks!

Comment: Is there something which says against `Dictionary<int, Tool>` and an appropriate `Tool.ToString()`?

Comment: As long as you don't mind a recompile whenever the descriptions change, `DescriptionAttribute` should be enough (what was the code that didn't work for you?). But frankly, it would be much less hassle for you if you used a `Dictionary<int, string>` and unless the integers you mention have the same "permanent" quality that e.g. a GUID has, an enum doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Vlad not that I know of. I forgot to mention that I consider myself new to c#, so I am willing to listen to whatever someone else thinks my work and at least give it a try. I just went with an Enum at first because it looked kind of promising.

Comment: Why not reading a simple XML file as "known tools" `<tool id='1001' name="Hello World Tool" />`?

Comment: @Jon I can call the DescriptionAttribute by referencing the Enum name, and I can call the Enum name by referencing the corresponding integer, but I was not able to get them to work together so that I could call the DescriptionAttribute by referencing the corresponding integer for some reason. The Dictionary might be the best bet, if someone could give me a simple example on how it works, that would be great.

Comment: @VarnerBeast14: Well, first of all, you should work not with numeric constants but with objects. So you should better have a class `Tool`. Next, how to map an int onto `Tool` instance? It's of course `Dictionary`. Next, how to output a tool? There are different options, either a property `Name`/`UserFriendlyName` or an implementation of `ToString` (I would prefer the property approach).

Comment: @metadings Can I reference a XML file as easily as a Dictionary? If so,  I would probably look into that as I have more experience using XML because of working with Android.

Comment: @VarnerBeast14: you should perhaps _load_ a dictionary from an XML file. The XML file should store a configuration, so your program can load/deserialize all the tools from it.

Comment: @VarnerBeast14 ah no, didn't get exactly how you meant that with the Attribute. In Attributes you can only reference compile-time constant values - use sort of serial numbers for your tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend having a tool class with a few properties;

```
public class Tool
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the code that deals with these I would use a `Dictionary<int, Tool>`. Then if say you wanted the description for tool 1001 you would just do:

```
  Console.WriteLine(myTools[1001].Description);
```

Of course you could just use a `Dictionary<int, string>` but you'll probably find later on that you'll want more data associated with the tool so creating a class makes more sense.

Comment: @jsmith maybe my code base uses lowercase on all properties and underscores to denote a private field :P Anyways, I've appeased you.

Comment: This looks good. I will try and work something up and come back here when I finish. It looks promising, so thank you for the answer regardless.

Comment: I am using this method, but where do I actually enter the tool names? Within the class in a dictionary method, or elsewhere?

Comment: @VarnerBeast14 In the most simple scenario, you define your tools (including their names) at the beginning of your program, not within the Tools class.  In more complex programs, you could read in your tools from a file or database right before they need to be used, and possibly cache the results for fast use later.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good case for a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Example:

```
var tools = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {1001, "Tool 1"},
    {1002, "Tool 2"},
    {1003, "Tool 3"},
};

string tool1Name = tools[1001];
//toolName == "Tool 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums are very useful.  There is a time and place for them and in your example, you really shouldn't use them.  They represent a constant value in a strongly-typed fashion and can be used as `flags` if you mark them so.

For your situation, a class would work.

```
public class ToolItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public override ToString() { //...Your logic }
}
```

You could then use a `List<T>`. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, etc.. to hold a reference to them and use LINQ to work with the collections.